# Executing a PHP script containing a path to another PHP script in another location

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am trying to run a PHP code in a PHP file and it has another php script that needs to be executed but PHP cannot find it. The other PHP script is in another path location than the php file that is called from.

I get an error from PHP about the script that is being called from /Users/peter/Documents/firm/worlddiki/na/ejs

The script from which the following is called is located at location

```
/Users/peter/Documents/firm/worlddiki/na/ejs
```

```
ERROR:
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/scripts/checkcmtimg.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php6') in /homepages/27/d468941446/htdocs/na/ejs/efranky.php on line 102
```

Any help would be appreciated in understanding how the php works in terms of paths.

Comment: Did you mean `./scripts/...`?

Comment: I continue to receive the message from php --> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/scripts/fucntionx.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php6') in /homepages/27/d468941446/htdocs/na/ejs/ed_s.php on line 102 when i use the code as in php that is calling the php script as <?php

          require_once("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/scripts/functionx.php");
          
          echo done_with_html;
?>

Comment: Any help in figuring this out would be appeciated.

Answer (score 0):

The include path only applies if you give a *relative* pathname.  You gave an *absolute* pathname (starts with "/"), so PHP was looking for the file in /scripts (that is, at the root directory of your computer).

You have two options:

- Use a relative pathname, like "./scripts/checkcmtimg.php" or simply "scripts/checkcmtimg.php".
  This will involve the include_path, searching each directory in the include path for that relative path.
- Use an absolute pathname, like "/Users/peter/Documents/firm/worlddiki/na/ejs/scripts/checkcmtimg.php".
  This will not use the include_path, it will search for the file in just the one location.

Comment: Might help to keep the paths in a project relative, using the magic `__DIR__` constant, or defining some custom base path constant in an include file? Edit: the formatter replaced my underscores xD